# Single Sign-On in Windows Applications using AD login

Tags: windows, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, windows-authentication

I need to setup Single Sign-On with with which if user login to Windows it will generate token that will enable him to login to other window applications.

I was searching for the same and I found that it can be done with Kerberos and Integrated Windows Authentication(IWA).

Can anyone point me to detailed steps?

Comment: Are you looking for an SSO vendor product that supports IWA/Kerberos for cross domain authentication, or are you looking for a Windows single domain implementation?

Comment: I am looking for Single Sign On with Windows Domain Account. Something similar to http://wiki.pmease.com/display/QB60/Single+Sign-On+with+Windows+Domain+Account with better explanation.

Comment: Which language do you want to use?

Comment: I am looking for authentications using Apache or htaccess.

Comment: I can point you to a good tutorial on this, if you're still interested.